# select only when an item exists on a table 3 or more times postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have 2 tables.  SalesOrderDetail and SalesOrderHeader.

SalesOrderDetails contains SalesOrderID and ProductID columns. 
SalesOrderHeader contains SalesOrderID and CustomerID.

I want to make a query that shows all the Customers who ordered 3 or more products with different ProductID and how many orders he made(with 3 or more different products). I know that a customer made an order of 3 or more products when the table SalesOrderDetail have his SalesOrderID number more than 3 or more times.

[image: SalesOrderDetail Table]

[image: SalesOrderHeader Table]

So the Customer with ID 29825 has ordered 12 different Products.

And here's my code:

```
SELECT "SalesOrderHeader"."CustomerID", count("SalesOrderDetail"."SalesOrderID") AS TotalOrders
FROM
    public."SalesOrderHeader",
    public."SalesOrderDetail"
WHERE
    "SalesOrderHeader"."SalesOrderID" = "SalesOrderDetail"."SalesOrderID" 
GROUP BY "SalesOrderHeader"."CustomerID"
HAVING count("SalesOrderDetail"."SalesOrderID") >= 3
```

Problem with this is that is shows the number of products he ordered but I want the total orders with 3 or more different products.

Comment: Please show the results that you want to get.  It is unclear what you want to return.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/bf4adb Here's my results. It shows 12 because that's how many times his SalesOrderID exists on the table. I want it to be 1 because that's one order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the total orders with 3 or more products per customer, then use two levels of aggregation:

```
select soh."CustomerID", count(*) as NumOrders
from public."SalesOrderHeader" soh join
     (select SalesOrderID, count(distinct ProductID) as numproducts
      from public."SalesOrderDetail" sod
      group by SalesOrderId
     ) sod
     on sod."SalesOrderID" = soh."SalesOrderID"
where numproducts >= 3
group by soh."CustomerID"
```